# Constant length for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Recently i came accross one issue. The issue though is not impacting my process but will make the GUI look good if resolved.

Issue is...I have a search screen where on the basis of search criteria some records are filtered which are displayed in a gridview having some ItemTemplate defined. My problem is the grid's length is adjusting according to the number of records in the grid. I need to have a constant height of grid so that my page length remains constant for all searches. This height should only be increased only when user wishes to show more than 10 records per page.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: You can use custom page grid like this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32145/Custom-paging-for-Gridview-DataGrid-DataList-and-R

Answer (score 1):

since your requirement is:  *you have a button say " Show More", when clicked displays next more 10 rows.*

One way is to use `List` of `objects` and then call [`List<T>.GetRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method. you can also return only the required number of records using `Take(n)` extension in `LINQ`, in case you are using this already. I had  `CountToDisplay` as a variable to save the current number of records to display, intially set to 0 (Zero)

`GetEmployees` method

```
protected List<Employee> GetEmployees(int CountToDisplay)
{
List<Employee> employees= new List<employee>();

// Sample code to fill the List. Use the `Take` Extension
    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();
    var e= ( from c in db.Employees
            select c ).Take(CountToDisplay);

     //iterate through results and add to List<Employee>
     foreach(var c in e)
     {
         employee emp = new employee { name = c.name, address = c.address };
         employees.Add(emp);
     } 
     return employees;

}
```

Here `Employee` is a class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
}
```

Now comes the interesting part. Suppose you have a button " Show More", when clicked displays next more 10 rows. This goes on until you reach the end. So in my case I used a link button and used a server method when clicked to load and refresh the grid.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowMore" class="ShowMoreLink" runat="server"
 OnClick="ShowMoreResults"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And this is the `ShowMoreResults` function:

```
private void ShowMoreResults()
        { 

    // Keep incrementing with the Minimum rows to be displayed, 5, 10 ...
    CountToDisplay = CountToDisplay + 
    Convert.ToInt16(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmpGridViewMinCount"]);

   // finally called the Grid refresh method
    RefreshGrid();    

            }
```

Grid Refresh method:

```
private void RefreshGrid()
        {
              List<Employee> employees = GetEmployees(CountToDisplay)
              if (employees != null)
                {                    
                  empGrid.DataSource = employees;
                }
// **Hide the ShowMore link in case Count to display exceeds the total record.**
               btnShowMore.Visible = employees.Count > CountToDisplay;
               // Finally bind the GridView
               empGrid.DataBind();
      }
```